# Angular routing setup 404 error, probably operator error

Tags: html, angularjs, webstorm

I have the following code which is giving me the old

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

error and I'm not seeing my views. The `main.js` file is on the same level in the project as `index.html`.

I built it in Webstorm 10 and I've been staring and rearranging stuff for two days now. I'm starting to get cross-eyed looking at it. If anyone can point out what I'm missing or if I wrote something wrong, it'd be a big help.

**EDIT :**

I edited the html because this was missing the `ng-view` element. I'm using the localhost server built into Webstorm to debug. The first template that should be seen upon the project being loaded, `about.html`, was the file that couldn't be loaded from the project. For that matter though, I get an error trying to load each of the templates.

**EDIT 2:**

I'm getting the idea it has something to do with Webstorm. If I start a default Angular project and fire it up in a browser, I get a whole bunch of failure to load resource errors.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<link href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="content/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<base href="/" />
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top cstmNavbar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse"
                aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/voiceover">Voice Over</a></li>
            <li><a href="/conventions">Conventions</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="/other">Other Links</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/views/about.html',
    controller: 'aboutCtrl'
})
.when('/voiceover', {
    templateUrl: '/views/voiceover.html',
    controller: 'voiceoverCtrl'
})
.when('/conventions', {
    templateUrl: '/views/conventions.html',
    controller: 'conventionsCtrl'
})
.when('/contact', {
    templateUrl: '/views/contact.html',
    controller: 'contactCtrl'
})
.when('/other', {
    templateUrl: '/views/other.html',
    controller: 'otherCtrl'
})
.otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
app.controller("mainCtrl", function ($scope) {

});
app.controller("aboutCtrl", function ($scope) {

});
app.controller("voiceoverCtrl", function ($scope) {

});
app.controller("conventionsCtrl", function ($scope) {

});
app.controller("contactCtrl", function ($scope) {

});
app.controller("otherCtrl", function ($scope) {

});
```

Comment: Looks like index.html got cut off. Can you repost the entire thing?

Comment: since you are using `html5Mode`, your server has to be configured uniquely in order for this to function.  Which server are you using, and what does it's routing service look like?  A server *is not optional* with html5Mode.

Comment: A 404 error is about a specific file. While file is not being found?

Comment: I edited my post with answers to your questions.

Comment: Are you running the project in a web server for testing?

Comment: Just Webstorm's localhost server

Comment: Which file can't it find?

Comment: It can't find any of the templates, but initially about.html.

Comment: so if you take off the leading `/` of the templateUrl does it work?

Comment: Negative, I'm getting the same result.

Comment: Webstorm ***is not*** a web server.  as I stated in my previous commentary, **It is not possible to use `file://` urls on the local disk drive when using `html5Mode`**.

Comment: You stated no such thing in your previous commentary, but thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Add in yor html code

```
<ui-view></ui-view>
```

This tag load html view

Comment: It was there in my code, the code just didn't fully format when I copied it onto here, so it was missing from the post.